# How to really completely completely remove pgadmin4 web version from ubuntu (nothing works)

Tags: python, django, pgadmin-4

I have tried this:

```
sudo apt -y remove pgadmin4
sudo apt -y autoremove pgadmin4*
```

It does not work

I have tried this:

```
pip3 uninstall pgadmin4
```

it does not work

while it says "successfully removed" it is not!

The problem is that I have forgotten the password so uninstalling and installing does not help because it does not give me a chance to reenter the new data:

So I have gone to

```
env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
LOG_FILE = '/var/log/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.log'
SQLITE_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db'
SESSION_DB_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'
STORAGE_DIR = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage'
SERVER_MODE = True
```

and removed the stored sessions, the config_loca.py file and still does not work because when I run this:

```
python3 venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4/setup.py
```

it does not pop me up to enter email and password like the first time I installed it but it just reads:

```
pgadmin4 application initialisation
```

I am going insane about it.
I cannot use the reset password because I still don't have the SMTP mail thing installed on my web.

Answer (score 0):

It was not enough to delete the files in their last directories, I also had to delete the directories themselves. Here:

```
LOG_FILE = '/var/log/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.log'
SQLITE_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db'
SESSION_DB_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'
STORAGE_DIR = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage'
SERVER_MODE = True
```

so delete pgadmin4, pgadmin4, sessions, and storage too.